# Why doesn't Tig have the Sons of Anarchy tattoo on his back similar to Jax?

Tags: plot-explanation, sons-of-anarchy

While watching Sons of Anarchy Season 5 Episode 3: "*Laying Pipe*" I noticed that Tig doesn't have the Sons of Anarchy logo tattooed on his back.

However, I assumed that all members have this tattoo, especially seeing as they went to great lengths to burn it off the back of Kyle Hobart (an excommunicated traitor) early on in the first season episode "*Giving Back"*.

Is there a reason why Tig doesn't have this tattoo?

Comment: rewatch the episode Clay has a back tattoo happy blacks it out

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not all members have the tattoo on their on their back. Some members have the tattoo on their arms. In the episode "Poor Little Lambs" of season 7, Juice is seen also without a back piece.